# Report (log) of each transaction on SQL Server Replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I've configured a transactional type of Replication between two SQL Servers. Since it's a project that it's still under review on my side I have only selected a couple of articles for the replication. For now, these tables will only have a couple of records updated per day or new ones.

What I'm trying to work out now is to get some sort of report that would describe the changes that happened during the transaction. It doesn't have to be very specific, maybe getting *how many rows went on the transaction*, *which tables, etc*. If it's that general it will not affect me, after all, all I want is to have some information that would help me to review all changes during the replication.

I have reviewed [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/replication-stored-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), about some tables and store procedures that could give me information on the replication, some of them are very useful like the information of the subscriber, publisher, the agent, etc. And in all of that, I saw that **dbo.MSdistribution_history** table stores good information.

> select * from dbo.MSdistribution_history

In this image, the first two rows are examples of the log information that I could only see within two minutes of a completed transaction.
[image]

After each successful transaction (pull and push of data between servers) I get some records with "A transaction(s) with two commands were delivered" (see previous) that with the timestamp are a good start for me. But after a couple of minutes, those types of rows are cleaned from this table and I lost the visibility.

Do you know of any table or store procedure that could help me get this information? The table(s) that were impacted, count of rows or commands that were executed, and date-time of the transaction?

Thank you

Comment: As you yourself state, it's called [audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @mustaccio thanks for your reply, but I don't see how this option could actually help me accomplish what I want (my scope is just the information regarding transactional replication). Using the word "audit" (which I'm going to change) in this context is specifically in knowing what changes were made during the transactional commands, how many rows and the timestamp. I will further review if your proposed article could help me.